# can't start docker via wsl powershell command but can start it in Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, bash, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running WSL2 / Ubuntu 20.04 / Windows 10.

When I type `sudo bash -c 'dockerd &'` in Ubuntu 20.04 / bash dockerd starts.

When I type `wsl sudo bash -c "dockerd &"` in PowerShell dockerd does not start.

Any ideas? Maybe & has some special meaning in PowerShell and needs to be escaped? If so idk how to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following did the trick:

```
wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04 -u <username> sudo bash -c -i "dockerd &"
```